# Phragmen Lindelof theorem, finding counterexample

Tags: complex-analysis

The version of Phragmen Lindelof theorem we work with saying that for $f$ holomorphic on the complex sector: $S=(z|-\pi/4 < arg(z) < pi/4)$ and continuous
on $\bar S$.

If $|f(z)|<1$ on $\partial S $ and there existing such constants $c,C >0 $ , $|f(z)|<Ce^{c|z|}$

So $\forall z \in S $ $|f(z)|<1$

I need to find counterexample to the case when the last condition:"there existing such constants $c,C >0$ , $|f(z)|<Ce^{c|z|}$" not happening, and so the argument that $\forall z \in S $ $|f(z)|<1$ would be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple counterexample is 
$$\frac{1}{2}e^{z^2}.$$
We can observe that if $z=r(1\pm i),$ then $\lvert f(z)\rvert <1$ but $f(r)\to\infty$ as $r\to\infty, r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: can you please give me justifcation for why $1/2*e^{|z|^2} > Ce^{c|z|}$ for every $c,C>0$ and for every $z \in S$

Comment: Nope, that's not true. A counter example should satisfy: For every $c;C>0$, there $\textbf{exists}$ $z\in S$ such that $|e^{z^2}|/2 >Ce^{c|z|}.$ Note that $e^{r^2}$ grows much faster than $Ce^{cr}$ as $r\to\infty$.